# SQL SERVER 2012: Subtract elements in a single column

Tags: sql-server-2012

Is there an easy way in SQL Server 2012 to subtract the n+1 - n value in a column?

I.e. suppose I have data like this.

```
    name value
    matt 25
    val  100
    hal  75
    brit 0
```

I want to get a result like this

```
    name value subtract
    matt 25    25
    val  100   75
    hal  75   -25
    brit 0    -75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure but you need to specify the order of your query. Use LAG with a window function.

```
SELECT name, value, value - LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY newid()) FROM your table
```

The `order by newid()` you need to replace with your desired order.

See fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1598b/6